# Where and how pool difficulty(pdiff) is set in bitcoin source code?

Tags: target, bitcoin

I am working with bitcoin source code  want to set initial difficulty to 1 (I changed bdiff,nBits field). So I need to change pdiff as well. according to :

> difficulty = difficulty_1_target / current_target (target is a 256
>   bit number)
>
> difficulty_1_target can be different for various ways to measure
>   difficulty. Traditionally, it represents a hash where the leading 32
>   bits are zero and the rest are one (this is known as "pool difficulty"
>   or "pdiff"). The Bitcoin protocol represents targets as a custom
>   floating point type with limited precision; as a result, Bitcoin
>   clients often approximate difficulty based on this (this is known as
>   "bdiff").

Anyone knows where pdiff is stored ? Is it hard coded ?

Comment: Bitcoin Core has nothing to do with pools.

Comment: Assume that I changed bdiff manually. How can I start up bitcoind server to get initial difficulty of 1?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution! It's not exactly a pdiff field in the code but there is a function in blockchain.cpp :

```
double GetDifficulty(const CBlockIndex* blockindex)
{
    if (blockindex == nullptr)
    {
        return 1.0;
    }

    int nShift = (blockindex->nBits >> 24) & 0xff;
    double dDiff =
        (double)0x0000ffff / (double)(blockindex->nBits & 0x00ffffff);

    while (nShift < 29)
    {
        dDiff *= 256.0;
        nShift++;
    }
    while (nShift > 29)
    {
        dDiff /= 256.0;
        nShift--;
    }
    return dDiff;
 }
```

for bitcoin initial nBits is equal to 0x1d00ffff so dDiff field above becomes 1 and nshift is equal to 1D. For my private version I set nBits to 0x1f0fffff and should calculate dDiff like

```
double dDiff =(double)0x000ffff / (double)(blockindex->nBits & 0x00ffffff);
```

and nShift field for me is 0x1f so I changed while conditions to `while(nShift < 31)` and`while (nShift > 31)`. by running command `bitcoin-cli getdifficulty` I got 1 as initial difficulty.